# VPN tunnel to two services on two servers?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, openvpn

I've got 2 CentOS 6.5 servers, each running one service:

- **server A**: `10.140.54.1/27` running service MySQL port 3306
- **server B**: `10.140.54.2/27` running service httpd port 443

Server B's `httpd` service is configured like so:

```
<VirtualHost 10.140.54.2:443>
    ServerName admin.domain.com
    ...
```

Servers are protected with Cisco firewall and there are no rules in `iptables` on either server.

I configured on server A a OpenVPN TCP tunnel and I can see the tunnel's interface like this:

- **server A**: `10.8.0.1/32`

I can connect my client and on the client I can see:

- **VPN client**: `10.8.0.6/30`

Everything seems to be fine even though there are no `iptables` rules or even when I disable `iptables` it's still fine, and I can connect to server A's services from the VPN client machine.

#### QUESTION

- How do I allow the VPN client to connect to the `httpd` service on server B?
- What `iptables` rules, if any, do I need to add?

In short I want the VPN client to be allowed to connect only to two services:

- server A's MySQL
- server B's httpd